# From a string remove '-' and then print first 10 charecters in shell script

Tags: unix

I have a string say 'Far-mers-market'. I need all the hyphens gone first and then extract the first 8 characters into a variable.

```
s1='Far-mers-market'
s2=Farmersm
```

Comment: Thanks works perfect

Comment: @lurker Please quote `'$s1'` (try solution with `s1='* -$(ps)-$(pwd)'`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `${string//substring/replacement}` to replace the `-` from the string s1, where omission of `/` before `replacement` means deletion. And then apply the `cut` command in the pipeline to get the first 8 characters with `-c` flag and list the character positions(in your case 1-8)

```
s1='Far-mers-market' 
s2=$(echo ${s1//-} | cut -c 1-8)
echo $s2
```

Comment: Better `s2=$(echo "${s1//-}" | cut -c 1-8); echo "$s2"`

Answer (score 0):

Avoid expanding the string in an efficient way:

```
s1='* -$(ps)-$(pwd)'
s2="${s1//-}"
s2="${s2:0:8}"
echo "${s2}"
```